# Tesseract can not recognize captcha text

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to recognize the text in a captcha and it is not possible for me. I am using python3, openCv and tesseract.

The simplified code is:

```
import cv2                                                           
from pytesseract import *

img_path = "path"

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

I think I should remove the color lines first, then leave the text alone, and maybe change the brightness and contrast. What filter could apply?

These are some images to recognize.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds to me like the CAPTCHA is working correctly.

Comment: Of course it cannot, you think why they invented CAPTCHA?

Answer (score 0):

For recognising captcha text using pytesseract-ocr, you can do the following..

- Prepare custom train_set to training your tesseract instance to recognise a specific font **[Optional]**
- The captcha images need some pre-processing(such as * Apply Black & White Filter > Scale(up) > Blur > Morphological Transformation + Adaptive threshold*)to enhance the text part and reduce the noises/lines.
- For removing lines: In the sample images only the text can be seen in black color and there is no black line, so you can simply convert the each non-black pixel to white by using PIL or OpenCV, you can even utilize some specific algo like Hough Line Transform to detect and remove lines.

You can learn about all these filters and algos from the official documentation and tutorial on OpenCV website.